# What determines the available ECMAScript version?

Tags: javascript, vba, with-statement

I've been assigned to debug an old Visual Basics website, in which we only have access to the JavaScript.

The issue is that there have been used "With" statements all over the place, some even including "remove()" inside.

This made me wonder, is it the browsers determining the available version of ECMAScript, or is it something else? Because if it's the browser then i guess i can use "let" to solve most of the scoping issues i'm guessing "with" has been used to solve.

Edit:
An example of how the with statements are used in the code (context for this can be found in comments):

```
function firstFunction(input1) {

    var someVariable = document.getElementById('someId');

    var i = someVariable.options.length;

    with (someVariable) {
        options[i] = new Option();
        options[i].text = input1.Name;
        options[i].value = input1.Id + ';' + input1.Type;
        i++;
    }
}

function secondFunction(input2) {

    var someVariable = document.getElementById('someId');

    var i = someVariable.options.length;

    with (someVariable) {
        options[i] = new Option();
        options[i].text = input2.PrettyName;
        options[i].value = input2.Name;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `let` wont' help if you need internet exploder support

Comment: I should note that the VB `With` statement doesn't solve *scoping* issues.

Comment: it "supports" const and let, but, the functionality (in my experience) is nothing like ES6

Comment: @CertainPerformance - IE11 has `const` and `let`, but the semantics are wrong (they don't work the way ES2015 defines them). (Why not? Because IE11 shipped before the definition was complete, and they jumped the gun on what they supported.) `for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); }, 0); }` will log `3` three times on IE11, instead of logging `0`, `1`, and `2`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, interesting, I'm surprised there are no [implementation notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility) about that on MDN

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Oooh, so am I. Will have to fix that and send a pull request (that part of the page isn't directly editable) in the next couple of days when I get a chance.

Comment: @Anders Oh, and as always, if you want to be able to write in ES6+ (which is great) and have crappy browsers understand your code, you may use Babel to automatically transpile your code from ES6+ syntax to ES5

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Filed [a bug for it](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/3198), will fix sometime this week. :-)

Comment: Also your example code could be fixed by getting the collection instead `function secondFunction(input2) {

    var options = document.getElementById('someId').options;

    var i = options.length;

     options[i] = new Option();
     options[i].text = input2.PrettyName;
     options[i].value = input2.Name;
     i++;}`

Comment: Picking up on @mplungjan's point, the [`Option` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) accepts the text and value, and the [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmloptionscollection) object has an `add` method, so: `document.getElementById("someId").options.add(new Option(input2.PrettyName, input2.Name));`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I never used add since it was not supported in older FX/Chrome  - don't you mean `HTMLSelectElement.add()`  by the way? There are holes in the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection

Comment: @mplungjan - No, I mean [`HTMLOptionsCollection#add`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-htmloptionscollection-add), which has been supported by every major browser for at least 15 years, possibly more (whereas `HTMLSelectElement#add` was more hit-and-miss).

Comment: (I guess now that private fields and methods use `#`, we need a new shorthand notation for `HTMLOptionsCollection.prototype.add`... :-) )

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I hail from far longer ago than 15 years ;) My first scripts had `if (document.images)` test for IE3.x

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i need to add both text and value to my option in most cases so i did this:

function functionName(input) {
    var option = new Option();
    option.text = input.Name;
    option.value = input.id + ';' + input.Type;
    document.getElementById('someId').options.add(option);
}

Is there a smarter way of doing so?

Comment: @AndersJensen - Yes, [see above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720000/what-determines-the-available-ecmascript-version?noredirect=1#comment94295038_53720000).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ahh yes, i missed that one. Sorry about that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is the "i" being used in the original code example just being used to push to the end of the option collection? 

Sorry if this is obvious, but i have never encountered these with blocks before, and i'm stille fairly new to JavaScript.

Comment: @AndersJensen - Yes, that's right. In JavaScript, you can add to an array by assigning to the first place beyond the end (odd as that may seem if you're used to true arrays; [JavaScript's are not true arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)), and many non-array collections/lists behave the same way, including the `HTMLOptionsCollection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the JavaScript engine used by the browser: V8 in Chrome, Chromium, and Opera; SpiderMonkey in Firefox; JScript in IE8; and Chakra in IE9+ and Edge (the verson of Chakra in IE9+ is very out-of-date; Edge's is quite up-to-date).

Comment: To be accurate, Chakra versions in IEs are also JScript engines.

Comment: @Teemu - Yeah, but it's fairly standard to refer to the pre-Chakra JScript as JScript and Chakra as Chakra.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just the answer i was hoping for, thanks a lot. 

If the With statement isn't used to solve scoping issues, then what do you use it for? 

I have edited the post with a pseudo example of how it's used in the code i'm working with.

Comment: @AndersJensen - VB's `With` doesn't solve *scoping* issues, it just makes it possible to avoid retyping an object reference. JavaScript's `with` doesn't solve any scoping issues either; [it *creates* them](https://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/). In the JS code you've quoted, I'd just repeat `someVariable` rather than using `with` (not least because I always use strict mode, and `with` is disallowed in strict mode).

Comment: @AndersJensen - Actually, you [don't even need the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53720000/what-determines-the-available-ecmascript-version/53720031#comment94295038_53720000).